Awaiting user with vuefire and Nuxt3
There are a lot of examples on how to use useCurrentUser with Nuxt3 and vuefire, however, the only example I found for getCurrentUser was in a middleware, not on a page.
So, I have a middleware that protects a page.
// middleware/auth.ts
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware(async (to, from) => {
  const user = await getCurrentUser();

  // redirect the user to the login page
  if (!user) {
    return await navigateTo({
      path: "/",
      query: {
        redirect: to.fullPath,
      },
    });
  }
});

And pages/my-page.vue
<script setup lang="ts">
definePageMeta({
    showHeader: true,
    middleware: ["auth"]
});

const _auth = useFirebaseAuth();
const db = useFirestore();
const user = await getCurrentUser();

if (!user) {
    throw new Error("No user?");
}

const idToken = await user.getIdToken();
// Use the token for API calls etc etc etc
</script>

Since I can reach this page, I obviously have a user. But this page would return No user? error.
I can't figure it out.
P.S. Replacing the call with const user = useCurrentUsers works, but I want to await the user before continuing with the process...

User authentication isn't something you should "await" on a page.  It's an event that can happen unpredictably (both signin and signout), so you're supposed an auth state observer to receive those events and decide what to do with them.  Start with the example in the documentation.

However, that might be probably what useCurrentUsers actually uses, and if that's the case, that's what you should be using anyway.  Don't try to get the auth state once and be done with it.  Instead, expect that it can change at any time, and respond to the change in state.
